# PHP code in an input text-box value doesn't generate PHP code

Tags: php, forms, variables, input

I have a file called form.php which is just a regular html file with the addition of the following:

```
<form>
<input type="text" value="<?php if(!empty($_GET['type'])) {echo(htmlspecialchars($_GET['type']));} ?>" />
</form>
```

The problem is that when I open the file, the actual PHP code itself is displayed in the text field, instead of getting the variable 'type.' How do I solve this?

Comment: How do you open the PHP file?

Comment: do you have it saved as a php file? are you running it via a php compatible server? (apache etc...)

Comment: I just tried to run it locally in my browser. I'm now going to upload it to my website and test it.

Comment: if you want to test it locally, you can set up XAMPP to create a functional webserver on your localhost. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP module is not loaded or not installed. Check your server's configuration

Comment: oh, right. that could make sense. i was just trying to test it locally.

Answer (score 0):

You say the code is in a "regular html file", does that mean the file is, for example, "`myfile.html`"? If so, rename it to "`myfile.php`" and that should solve your problem.